# Composing images using framebuffer objects

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I'm trying to make some "images" within OpenGL ES 2.0 but I'm having some problems. What I want is to build a framebuffer object, let's say one of 400x300 pixels, and then render some graphics using an orthogonal projections.

The way I create the framebuffer object I think is right. This is the vertex array which holds it:

```
GLfloat vertexData[] = {
// X      Y     Z     U     V
  -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
   0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
   0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
  -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
};
```

Later, I create the texture and renderbuffer with the same size (i.e. 400x300). Also, I don't really know if the previous vertexData is right, shouldn't it be using 400x300 instead 1x1 ?

Also, the problem arrives when I build the projection and view matrix:

```
_projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 400.0f, 300.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
_view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0,0,1), glm::vec3(0,0,0), glm::vec3(0,1,0));
```

When I use them, I don't see anything on the screen. However when I set them to identity matrix I see my painted graphics to the framebuffer object, but of course I want to map pixel coordinates to opengl coordinates in order to draw images easily.

This is the code I use to draw the elements painted to the framebuffer object:

```
// Bind the framebuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebufferObject);

// Set viewport to size of texture map and erase previous image
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, 400, 300);

// Render every GraphicComponents to the FBO
for(GraphicComponent* gc : _graphicComponents) {
  gc->render();
}

// Unbind the FBO so rendering will return to the backbuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glViewport(0, 0, _screenWidth, _screenHeight);
```

The render method of the GraphicComponent class just draws the element. For example, for a RectangleComponent:

```
void RectangleComponent::render() {
    _shader.useProgram();

    glVertexAttribPointer(_colorHandler, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _vertexData);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_colorHandler);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(_mvpHandler, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(_projectionMatrix * _viewMatrix * _modelMatrix));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indices);

}
```

Which works really fine when I draw it outside of my framebuffer object.

**TL;DR** I want to draw some elements like rectangles, texts, etc to a framebuffer object but I don't know which sizes (or vertex positions) use for my elements when they are rendered to the framebuffer object. Also, I want the elements in the framebuffer object be rendered in an orthogonal projection, so they have their opengl coordinates mapped to screen pixels and their upper-left corner at (0,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was doing it right , however my environment is a bit weird (I'm using a projector, not a screen) and I have to deal with it.

The only change I've made, is to use identity matrix as a view matrix, since it's not needed, and set the vertex data array to:

```
GLfloat vertexData[] = {
// X        Y       Z     U     V
  -400.0f,  300.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
   400.0f,  300.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
   400.0f, -300.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
  -400.0f, -300.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
};
```

The orthogonal projection matrix was right.

Answer (score -1):

when drawing to FBO you most likely want use ortho projection so you can use "pixel" coordinates.

to draw texture from FBO as full screen quad use identity projection matrix and

```
GLfloat vertexData[] = {
// X      Y     Z     U     V
  -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom-right
  -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Top-left
   1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom-right
   1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f  // Top-left
};
```

and then draw glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRING, 0, 4); so you don't need use index array.

Comment: This is totally irrelevant to my question, since it's not what I'm asking.